# Dynamic memory allocation, reallocating and calculating sum after each input

Tags: c

I'm bit stuck with this exercise for hours;

[image]

As you can see, get a number, dynamically allocate a memory, and if the number is minus, reduce the size of it, and calculate the sum after each input.

My code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int number;
    int count = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int *ap;
    printf("Input Value = ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    ap = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
    *ap = number;
    sum += *ap;
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum); /*getting the first value*/

    for( ; ;)
    {
        printf("Input Value = ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
        if (number < 0)
        {
            count--; /*reducing the size*/
            ap = (int*)realloc(ap, sizeof(int)*count); 
            for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ap)/sizeof(ap[0]); i++)
            {
                sum+=*ap;
            }
            printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
        }
        else
        {
            count++; /*increasing the size*/
            ap = (int*)realloc(ap, sizeof(int)*count);
            *(ap+(count-1)) = number;
            for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ap)/sizeof(ap[0]); i++)
            {
                sum+=*ap;
            }
            printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
        }
    }
    free(ap);
}
```

the memory allocation is not working properly I suppose, because when I print out sizeof(ap), it always print 4, not 4, 8, 12...

I hope someone can point out my mistake! Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a debugger could point on your mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should narrow your question to a specific part of the program that you need help with, in such a way that others could benefit from the answer.

Comment: `ap` is a pointer, apparently 4 bytes on your computer.  Changing the contents of its target has no effect on pointer size.

Comment: `sizeof(ap)` this is not going to work. `ap` is a poiner __not__ an array. The `sizeof` will always return a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is here -

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ap)/sizeof(ap[0]); i++)
```

You see, `sizeof` is an operator that returns a constant value when used with a pointer (`ap` here). It would work fine if `ap` was an array but not with pointers.

What you need to use is another variable to keep track of the size of `ap` and you already have it - `count`.

So just use `count` instead of `sizeof(ap)/sizeof(ap[0])`.

Also for future learn to use a Debugger because errors like these can be easily pointed out by Debuggers.